# over lays on overlays in Google maps

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

How can I create overlays on an overlay in Google maps?

It is possible to create custom overlays in Google maps and I succeeded in creating an image overlay. Now I want to create another overlay on the the overlay that I have created, how may I proceed?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. What is an overlay on an overlay? Do you mean *markers*? What have you tried so far, can you show some code?

Comment: You can put as many overlays on a map as you need, regardless of whether they overlap or not, or appear on top of each other. Just make sure you set the 'zIndex' on the overlays if you're getting problems with them not appearing on top.

Comment: You might also simply try it first (especially because it should not be a problem to have more than one overlay) and if you get stuck, ask a more specific question.